# Restore DotNet boostrapper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I'm developing an application C# with clickonce setup. I had a folder DotNetFX40 in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages` (visual studio 2015).

I wanted to modify the reboot mode but unfortunately I've made a mistake and now the setup doesn't work.

Where can I find an official version for this package ? (.NET framework 4.0)

I'm following instructions from [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130.aspx)